# jQuery.Validate - How to put errors results on a different and one place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to put all errors generated by jQuery.Validate in one place.

Ex:

```
    <input type="text" id="Text1" class=".name" />
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="text" id="Text2" />
    <input type="text" id="Text3" />
    <input type="text" id="Text4" />

    <div id="errors"> I want to put errors results here! </div>
```

I already tried to put like that, but doesn't work:

```
   jQuery('.name').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: 'Type a name'
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        errorLabelContainer: "#errors"
    });
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use errorPlacement like so:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo("#errors");
}
```

Comment: it will append content each time !

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use `errorLabelContainer`, but the way you are setting up jQuery Validate seems to be wrong.  You need to call `validate` on the **form** not the individual elements.  That's where you end up specifying all your rules and messages, along with the `errorLabelContainer`.  Furthermore, you'd need to specify `name` attributes on each input (an `id` attribute is not enough):

So imagine your form looks like this (in abbreviated fashion):

```
<form id="myFormId">
<input type="text" name="Text1" id="Text1" class=".name" />
</form>
```

Then you would have javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myFormId').validate({
        rules: {
           Text1: {
              required: true
           }
        },
        messages: {
          Text1: {
              required: 'Type a name'
          }
        },
        errorLabeLContainer: '#errors'
    });
});
```